# Nuxt SSR deployment on docker with pm2 has error,

Tags: docker, deployment, nuxt.js, pm2

Versions

```
 nuxt: v2.14.12
 node: v14.15.3
```

ecosystem.config.yaml :

```yaml
apps:
      - name: App
        exec_mode: cluster
        instances: max
        script: ./node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js
        args: start
```

I did run nuxt build command then,
when i run `pm2-runtime start ecosystem.yml` on docker, i get this error:

```
Error: No build files found in
/var/www/ui/ecosystem.config.yaml/.nuxt/dist/server.
Use either nuxt build or builder.build() or start nuxt in development mode.
```

how i can solve that?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and couldn't find any ways to solve it.
My temporary solution is deploying multiple docker containers with a load balancer by Nginx.
You can start with pm2-runtime if remove "instances: max" and "exec_mode: cluster" options to run in fork mode.

Comment: @HaiTH  i handled it without pm2 by call nuxt start command in container command. if you want more information send an email to me.